# Rails: wkhtmltopdf is not executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to get the wicked_pdf to work on localhost. The problem is, this error shows up, when trying to access it.

```
wkhtmltopdf is not executable
```

This is how I linked it

```
<%= link_to "Create PDF document", order_path(@order, format: :pdf) %>
```

This it the wicked_pdf inicializer

```
WickedPdf.config = {
    exe_path: Gem.bin_path("wkhtmltopdf-binary", "wkhtmltopdf"),
}
```

And this is the controller

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
        render pdf: "File",
        template: "orders/show.html.erb",
        layout: "pdf.html"
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Rails 6.